# Selenium doesn't match the text present

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide

My first question. I'm using 2.8.0 where verifyTextPresent is deprecated but I'm using it because verifyText requires the use of CSS locators and our data changes from time to time. Anyway, these days, I fire Selenium and do the testing as usual. However, it shows a no-match even though the text is present on the web page (and this behaviour is for one page only). What can I do about this?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:popupDers('02','2014','CULT','454','eng');">Cultures of Migration
</a>
```

**Selenium IDE code:**

```
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>/programscourses/currentcourses</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
  <td>Cultures of Migration</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>/programscourses/currentcourses</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
  <td>link=CULT 454</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

This one worked for me, thanks everyone for  replies and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as simple as the element hasnt loaded yet.  Try putting a wait in.

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>location of the element</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

You want to add this step in before your verify text step.

Comment: Thanks, but let me ask you something. How does my above text fit in here?

Comment: Heh, I did `<tr>  <td>waitForElementPresent</td><td>id=harf_ac_buton</td>  <td></td>
</tr>` but `verifyTextPresent` after it still turned red :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use waitForText. It will check for the element and if found assert it's text content.

Here is an example using https://www.google.com/ as the Base URL

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForText</td>
    <td>link=About</td>
    <td>About</td>
</tr>
```